# Нарисовать окружности на равном расстоянии друг от друга и центра

Tags: c#, canvas, математика, геометрия, рисование

Всем привет, столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Пишу программу для автоматического построения графов на канвасе (лабораторная). Не могу понять как его именно нарисовать.

У нас есть канвас заданного размера, есть n точек.

Нужно добиться следующего: на равном расстоянии от центра канваса нарисовать n окружностей (canvas.DrawCircle(x, y, 10);), которые будут на равном расстоянии друг от друга. n постоянно меняется.

Всю голову сломал, но алгоритм придумать не могу.

Полагаю, что нужно плясать от деления круга на сектора, вычисляя угол, а уже далее через полярные координаты, но как найти угол - не понимаю

Comment: Полагаю, что нужно плясать от деления круга на сектора, вычисляя угол, а уже далее через полярные координаты, но как найти угол - не понимаю

Comment: Что значит друг от друга?

Comment: @Igor равномерно распределены на окружности

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Расположите точки по окружности, центр совпадает с центром канваса.

Разделите 360 градусов на n - это будет приращение угла.

Ну и в цикле от 0 до n рисуйте окружности.

Координаты X, Y будут определяться тривиальными формулами:

> X = X1 + Radius * cos (angle)
>
> Y = Y1 + Radius * sin (angle)

Где X1, Y1 - координаты центра канваса.

Пример на JavaScript [см. тут](https://github.com/akmetainfo/3k-project), с канвасом и расчётом координат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]